# Responsive full screen grid

Tags: css, media-queries

My objectives are:

- full screen
- sidebar menu, and content
- when resized to mobile, menu on top, rest below
- thats it

I liked the Foundation grid. But I've found no 'legit' way to do that.

Is it possible, or what grid framework would you advise for that?

Comment: I listed several of the resources/grids out there here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12615201/451969 Smashing Magazine also has a lot of info, and [Antonion Carusone's Grid System site](http://www.thegridsystem.org/) includes linkes and archives that are pretty extensive. Khoi Vinh and Shaun Inman are two others to look into, if you're interested in the theory and the art.

Comment: This might also be useful: [Responsive Design Bookmarklet Generator](https://github.com/jonikorpi/responsive-design-bookmarklet-generator)

Comment: http://www.photoshopwireframingkit.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like all you really need is:

```
<body>
    <div id="navbar">...</div>
    <div id="content">...</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#navbar {
    position: fixed; 
    left: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;
    width: 150px;
    overflow: auto;
}
#content {margin-left: 150px;}
@media all and (max-width: 480px) {
    #navbar {
        bottom: auto; right: 0;
        height: 150px;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    #content {margin-left: 0; margin-top: 150px;}
}
```

Alternatively, have two navbars (one for normal devices, one for mobile) and just show/hide them using the media query.

Comment: There's more to it than that.